# ImportError: cannot import name 'K' from 'keras.layers'

Tags: keras, tf.keras

my tensorflow version is 2.4.0, and keras version is 2.4.3, when I do `from keras.layers import K`, the error occured, `ImportError: cannot import name 'K' from 'keras.layers'` . I think it must be version issue, but how can I change to a right Keras version?

Comment: Why don't you just use the keras under tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge there's no such layer known as K, i think you must be looking for the backend

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K # This is the most common usecase for keras using K
K.set_session(tf.Session())

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Conv2D, LSTM # Normally used like this if your using the layers, you can check out the official docs here https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html
```